# Best way to SUM all the columns between two particular columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

What should be the best approach to get a sum of cells that are between two columns A and E. Column A has a header of "Month Jan" and col E has a header of "Month Feb".

Columns are inserted and removed between A and E on daily basis. Meaning, sometimes column data with the header "Month Feb" is at col G, other times at col D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could something like this be useful? With INDEX and MATCH narrows to that column:

```
=SUM(A2:INDEX(A2:Z,,MATCH("Month Feb",A1:Z1,0)))
```

If you want to skip last column add -1:

```
=SUM(A2:INDEX(A2:Z,,MATCH("Month Feb",A1:Z1,0)-1))
```

### UPDATE

In order to include every column, going from Month Jan to Month Feb, even if there are added more columns to the left or right:

```
=SUM(INDEX(2:2,,MATCH("Month Jan",1:1,0)):INDEX(INDIRECT(ROWS(A:A)&":"&ROWS(A:A)),,MATCH("Month Feb",1:1,0)-1))
```

I've added one extra row to the top, so you see it working in the green cell:
I've added a GIF, but wasn't working well. Check here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gbAd1bwF9Mt3H6K7Wh-iJlU-GuDMZ9-Qc3DWReiLuxE/edit#gid=628124778

Comment: Hi Martin, thank you for taking the time to answer my question. Unfortunately that doesn't work in my case. Instead of -1, -2 worked somehow but not completly. By adding -2, I get the desired **sum** however when I add a column to the left of "Month Jan", sum function gives the wrong answer. Perhaps my question wasn't clear, my intention is to _add everything in between two columns i.e. "Month of Jan" and "Month of Feb" irrespective of their column alphabet identity_.

Comment: I've understood what you said earlier, but given that columns are added to the left "-1" won't be as reliable. I've created one formula that will sum from row 2 to the end of the rows, in between "Month Jan" and "Month Feb"

Comment: Wow it works, Thanks again. And now I can spend my coffee break on something productive, like learning the use of indirect and index/match in excel. Can't upvote your answer though, i don't habe enough "reputations".

Comment: I'm glad it was useful. Basically I called the whole row 2:2 and the whole last row, and selected the cell from the columns that matched the headers. Good luck! (You can actually mark the question as answered)